# Laravel 4 phpunit test: Test flagged as `risky` for not closing its own output buffers

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

I'm having a problem while trying to test a simple Illuminate\Http\Response object inside a phpunit test. The error in question is:

```
PHPUnit 4.3-dev by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /var/MyApp/phpunit.xml

....................R.................

Time: 2.71 seconds, Memory: 76.75Mb

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 38, Assertions: 55, Risky: 1.
```

where the R is shown when running `phpunit --tap` as

```
# RISKY Test code or tested code did not (only) close its own output buffers
```

The class that i want to test is:

```
class PrettyError {

    /**
     * Renders a pretty 500 error page view
     *
     * @return string with error view
     */
    public function render()
    {
             return Response::make(View::make('viewName')->with('param','value')->render(), 500, array());
    }
}
```

and the test is

```
class Pretty500Test extends BaseTest {

    /** @var Pretty500 */
    private $pretty500;

    /**
     * Set dependencies
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pretty500 = app(PrettyError::class);
    }

    public function testRender()
    {
        $response = $this->pretty500->render();

        //assertions below, never get reached cause tests aborts after above call
        $this->assertsTrue('500',$response->getStatus());
    }

}
```

Note that the same error occurrs when testing any route in my app using the laravel

`this->route('GET','routeName')`

helper method, so this seems to be a general error related to the Response request. As far as I can think of, there is nothing within my application that is doing anything funky with the output buffering (purposefully), which is the only thing I can think of that could mess up the standard working of the Response class.

I'm using phpunit 4.3-dev, laravel 4.2.1, and mockery for the tests.

I haven't found much at all on the internet in terms of this particular risky error code, so I'm at a loss without further help.

Comment: Try it on a clean install of Laravel - do you still get the issue?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it yet on a clean install yet, I'll do that next in order to make sure it's not something in the TestCase setup that I'm using

Comment: Update: I isolated the problem a bit more, and it's not related to the Request class itself, but to the inner View call, so basically

    `View::make('viewName')->with('param','value')->render()`

triggers the phpunit risky warning without anything else in the test. Since the `View` instance in my app is not the native laravel one but is hotswapped with a custom one  but builds on that (it registers some useful View composers) maybe there is something in there that the test doesn't like

Comment: Actually - I just noticed you are "making" a view, rendering it, then sending that to the Response class to be re-rendered?

Comment: Yeah, basically I'm creating a response with custom headers and status code, and it's content is just the rendered view. I took a look at the docs now and there is a shorthand method `Response::view('hello')->header('Content-Type', $type);` that can be used to do it at once, but apart from that it's correct AFAIK

Comment: I've updated my answer - Laravel can do all of that for you - no need for special functions.

Answer (score 10):

## Not good enough enclosed ternary operator (?)

I had the same problem with a risky testcase while testing in Laravel 5. The problem here was, that I had a code like the following in my navigation (default layout file):

```
<li{{ Request::is('clients*')?' class="active"':'' }}><a href="/clients">Clients</a></li>
```

The test did not like this section because the the ternary operator (the `?`) was not closed well enough. I replaced it with the following to get it working (added parantheses around the ternary operator section):

```
<li{{ (Request::is('clients*')?' class="active"':'') }}><a href="/clients">Clients</a></li>
```

I found this by removing the blade syntax part by part from the requested view, the layout it extended and the files that were included. At the point of removing the syntax above it worked, so there was the error.

## Empty yield / section

The same error occurred, when I passed an empty value for a yield, eg like in the following scenario:

**layout.blade.php**

```
<h1>@yield('title')</h1>
```

**page.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout')    
@section('title','') //<-- This empty value raised the error
```

## Other things to consider

Maybe clear but just in case you did the same mistake: You have to check all the involved files.

I had run the following test which visits the login page, enters email and password and presses the login button:

**tests/AuthenticationTest.php**

```
<?php
class AuthenticationTest extends TestCase
{
    // [...]

    public function testLoginSuccessful()
    {
        $password = str_random();

        $user = factory(App\User::class)->create(['password' => $password]);

        $this->visit(route('login'))
            ->type($user->email, 'email')
            ->type($password, 'password')
            ->press('Login')
            ->seePageIs(route('dashboard2'));
    }
}
```

**app/Http/routes.php**

```
<?php
Route::get('auth/login',    'Auth\AuthController@getLogin')->name('login');
Route::post('auth/login',   'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
```

**app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php**

```
<?php    
// [...]
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    // [...]

    protected $redirectPath = '/dashboard2'; // <-- check this file as well
}
```

So I had to check especially the following files where I made modifications:

- app/Http/routes.php
- app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php -> function getLogin
- resources/views/auth/login.blade.php (returned in Auth\AuthContoller@getLogin)
- app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php -> function postLogin
- resources/views/dashboard2.blade.php (returned on successful login)

Comment: Empty section caught me out too. Changing it to @section('name', null) made it not risky, but now looks like a code smell :-/

Comment: Ahh `@section('title','')` was causing issue. THanks!

Comment: For me I had to wrap the `@section('title')` in a `@hasSection` block - using `null` instead of `''` did not do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Happens also in Laravel 5.
PHPUnit will throw this when response format is incorrect.

It could be due to:

- Errors in Laravel app: check logs
- Incorrect Blade syntax: for instance in my case, there was an excessive Blade `@stop` which wasn't considered as an error by Laravel (and wasn't logged)

Comment: Was the same with my installation. Didn't have an @endsection to close an opened section in my template file.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in on this as well. I ran into this maddening risky matter while writing tests for Laravel 5.1app. This comment put me on the right path, and it turns out I had an obsolete `@show` statement in a Blade template, which was causing the problem. If you'd like to find all of the files having at least one for instance `@endsection` statement in your Laravel app (or any app for that matter), run the following command:

    grep -cr "@endsection" . | sed '/:0$/d' | sort -k2n -t:

This is useful because grep's default behavior is to list *all* files and the number of occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem is due to the view in question using

`Input::old()`

inside a form. After trying to simply access `Input::old('foo')` inside any phpunit test, I got a

`RuntimeException: Session store not set on request.`

So the real culprit was in the sessions store in my unit tests instead of any Request/View render problem. Problem was solved by setting the session storage for the current Request instance inside the testRender() method:

`\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::setSession($this->app['session.store'])`

Answer (score 1):

I have same error message from PhpUnit likes yours.. I have written '@stop'  on wrong line in view(blade) file.. I have edited  by moving  up right  '@stop' to right line and than  PHPUnit tests is passed!

Try to check your @section @stop block in your blade files..

Answer (score 0):

I've had very similar issue. The problem was that I was trying to get property of non object (NULL) in the view, but instead of PHP error 'Trying to get property of non-object' phpunit showed 'OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!'.

So if you have the same problem check for that kind of errors in the view file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a duplicated `@section('content')` line

```
@section('content')

@section('content')
...
@endsection
```

Bad typo !!